# Display Leaflet/OpenLayers with Qt but without QWebKit / QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

Currently I am displaying a geomap like Leaflet or Openlayers inside a QWebView. Therefore I need to include QWebKit with

```
#include <QWebView>  // Edit: not <QWebKit>
```

into my app. This raises memory usage as shown in windows task manager from 2.7 mb to 27 mb.

I noticed the increase of the memory even when I just add the corresponding source file of the map stuff (with the 'include') to the project (not instantiating any objects from it, e.g. I do not display the map then), but still the memory increases.

- Why does memory usage increase even without using the class?
- Is there an alternative to QWebView for showing and interacting with a map? I do not know which parts of QWebKit are really needed for the map stuff, otherwise I would try to search for a concrete library...

If I need to stick with QWebKit, can I deferr the memory allocation until the class is really needed? For example with QLibrary?

Comment: You're integrating a full web browser into your application. A web browser that integrates an application development framework, a JIT, and so on. 27mb is cheap. What are you running this on? Why is it a problem?

Comment: The memory for itself is not the main concern because it will be ran on desktop computers/notebooks. But the map itself is only a tiny part of the app and not the main purpose, and it is like 1% of app increases memory by 1000%. At least I would like to deferr the memory allocation until the map is really needed, which by default is not shown, only on request. Also I do not know if including the whole web browser as you say is not like using a sledge hammer for cracking nuts in my use case, hence the question for an alternative.

Comment: Your question why it was a problem is just that I want to minimize memory usage, because a lot of people would look at it and say "well thats huge memory for such an application, I won't use it. I suspect it doing something weird in the background" and so on... or be it just for the comparison with similar apps...

Comment: If you don't want the overhead of a web browser, don't use html content, then! I'm pretty sure you could write C++ code that fetches the same data/images that leaflet/openlayers uses and renders it. It'll have way lower overhead. HTML isn't free. I don't understand why you expect it to be free.

Comment: I do not expect it to be free. Just asked for better suited alternatives. Still thats only part of my question. I am ok with the memory if it would only be used when the map is shown. but it depends on source file inclusion which I do not understand. any explanation for that?